# I am getting error while initialize value containing ' using ng-init in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an error while initialize value containing **'** using ng-init in Angularjs.

for eg:

```
@{
var textToDisplay="Suman's Question";
<div ng-app="" ng-init="myText='@textToDisplay'">
<h1>{{myText}}</h1>
</div>
}
```

The above query throwing error

```
[$parse:lexerr]
```

I am using MVC for rendering the view.
Thanks in advance for the suggestion..

Comment: ng-init="myText='Suman\'s Question'" you need to handle this Suman`'`s

Comment: you couldn't put single quotation inside single quotation so you have to put escape character `\` so make it like this  ng-init="myText='Suman\'s Question'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is as follows

```
@{
var textToDisplay="Suman's Question";
textToDisplay= textToDisplay.Replace("'", "\\'");
<div ng-app="" ng-init="myText='@textToDisplay'">
<h1>{{myText}}</h1>
</div>
}
```

And if it is using " then the code is like.

```
@{
var textToDisplay="Suman"s Question";
textToDisplay= textToDisplay.Replace("\"", "&#34");
<div ng-app="" ng-init="myText='@textToDisplay'">
<h1>{{myText}}</h1>
</div>
}
```